# How to determine that UserControl has been loaded completely?

Tags: silverlight, image, preloading

How to determine that UserControl has been loaded completely?

I have some UserControls with images and media files from another server bound like that:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
```

I would like to know when all my images are downloaded and ready to be shown.
I've noticed an event ImageLoaded, and probably I can listen to it on all of my Image controls. Isn't there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The class FrameworkElement contains a public event called "Loaded", so naturally all classes derviving from it (UserControl class) expose it as well.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

The question would be : Are you downloading your images ? (This can be after loading of the control [Check here](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/preloading_displaying_image_pg1.htm)) Or are you embedding your images in the project? They'll be a part of the .xap file that's downloaded when you launch your application.

You can add an event handler to that event to execute code when the said event occurrs. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Images are from another server. So in my example Image property will something like `http://anotherserver.com/images/example.png`. Does the Loaded event fire after example.png image is downloaded nad placed in the control?

Comment: if you go for remote download scenario, the Loaded event will be fired before the images are downloaded - they need to be handled separately.